# Core Data - Dynamic (and Persistent) Object Creation and Manipulation

Tags: objective-c, class, object, core-data

I'm just a newbie to Core Data and Objective C, so I hope this question is coherent.

I have been working on an app that is fundamentally a group of NSTimers that fire repeatedly until told to change (with new parameters or stopped). Each timing scheme has its own allocated and initialised object, with methods in the header as shown below:

```
@interface CounterClass : NSObject

- (void)startCounting:(int)counterIncrement;

- (void)amendCounting:(int)newCounterIncrement;

- (void)stopCounting;

@end
```

Initially, the app was quite rigid in its data structure, limited to three counters. This made allocating the object and running it as required fairly straightforward. The counters could be explicitly named at the top of the implementation. Therefore, I could allocate the class, and refer to it in methods as required.

```
@implementation MainClass
{
    // Counter Objects
    CounterClass *counterA;
    CounterClass *counterB;
    CounterClass *counterC;
}

...

- (void)initialisingMethod
{
    counterA = [[CounterClass alloc] init];
    [counterA startCounting:1];
    counterB = [[CounterClass alloc] init];
    [counterB startCounting:2];
    counterC = [[CounterClass alloc] init];
    [counterC startCounting:5];
}

- (void)someOtherMethod
{
    [counterA amendCounting:2];
    [counterB amendCounting:9];
    [counterC amendCounting:4];
}

- (void)stoppingMethod
{
    [counterA stopCounting];
    [counterB stopCounting];
    [counterC stopCounting];
}
```

This arrangement is probably clunky in the eyes of others, but it's seemed to have worked quite nicely. **The objects persist after initialising them in initialisingMethod, and methods can be called upon as necessary throughout the program.**

However, now I have incorporated Core Data into the app, and am wanting to make the group of timing objects much more dynamic. The Core Data scheme I have currently is a single overall timing group entity, with a bunch of timers that are created as necessary by the user:

```
Entity - timingGroupInfo
Attributes - name, image
Relationships - timers (one to many)

Entity - timerSettings
Attributes - name, increment
Relationships - info (to one)
```

**What I am wanting to do is do away with the rigid set of three CounterClass objects, and be able to handle an unlimited number of counters from 1 to n, depending upon how many timerSettings entries are present in Core Data.**

I guess I could just make a huge number of CounterClass objects...:

```
@implementation MainClass
{
    // Counter Objects
    CounterClass *counterA;
    CounterClass *counterB;
    CounterClass *counterC;
    ...
    CounterClass *counterN;
}
```

... then iterate through the listed timerSettings and allocate them individually, but this technique seems rather crude and something that I want to avoid. **I'd prefer that the number of classes created would scale with the number of timerSettings entries, but I just have no idea how to accomplish this. The objects need to persist after initialisingMethod has completed, and the methods need to be able to be called upon later in someOtherMethod and stoppingMethod.**

Is there a name / best practice for this type of behaviour? I can't seem to nail down the right combination of keywords when doing a Google search. **I'm guessing what I need to do is somehow attach the methods to the individual NSManagedObject, and/or make use of the NSManagedObject Entity classes I have created (in this case, timingGroupInfo.h and timerSettings.h). Core Data is fresh terrain for me, so perhaps this may be a simple proposal for the experienced programmer.**

Open to ideas about the way I'm approaching this, as well (I'm still learning about Objective C!)

Answer (score 1):

> This arrangement is probably clunky in the eyes of others

Simple, but not extensible (certainly a standard learner approach)

> I guess I could just make a huge number of CounterClass objects

That doesn't really save you from the original problem. You need to think in terms of identification and collections instead. Where you currently have `someOtherMethod` which doesn't take a parameter identifying the timer to act upon - that's an issue (and presumably you have lots of those methods, each with similar names that act on each of the different timers)...

It isn't clear what the `increment` is used for, so I'll assume that your `CounterClass` is keeping a transient count that is incremented.

First, you have 2 classes for each timer currently: `TimerSettings` (note that I changed the name to follow conventions) and `CounterClass`. You don't really need 2 classes. `TimerSettings` is a perfectly good class and can hold transient information and have additional methods (you might want to look at [mogenerator](https://github.com/rentzsch/mogenerator) to help with that).

So, I'd drop `CounterClass` and just use `TimerSettings` (probably renaming it to just `MYTimer`, where `MY` is your project prefix - which you should have on all of your classes...)

Now, each of your `MYTimer` entities has a `name` and that can be used to display the timers to the user so they can start and stop them (if the user doesn't name them uniquely then you get to have fun and you should add some properly unique identifier, or use the `NSManagedObjectID`).

Note that you shouldn't need to do any iteration or filtering because:

1. You should be able to uniquely identify each `MYTimer`
2. All of your methods that act on an individual timer should take that timer, or the timer unique identifier as a parameter
3. Any time you get a unique identifier to use you can ask the managed object context for that timer (or a local cache dictionary with the identifier as the key and the `MYTimer` as the value)

Now that your objects are properly identified and your methods are parameterised you have a lot less code and a much greater ability to 'navigate' your data structure to find the timer that you want in order to deal with any particular use case.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The code in my question is simplified to make it as general as possible. The basic process for my app involves the user configuring a variable quantity of counters, then pressing 'play' for the counters to run NSTimers in the background (it is a sound application). I will have to think about what you've written... it could be that I haven't grasped the concepts properly.

Comment: So Core Data will allow you to configure a number of 'timers' without any issue. Your problems are just around how you present them to the user and allow the user to edit them (hence the identification and parameterisation issue). Each managed object can have a timer as a property. It's often better to ask about your real situation than to try to simplify, even if you change names but still describe the exact problem space.